# Get values that depend on 3 columns and one row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a budget table for the current month (Table 1) and a budget table with the budgets for all months (Table 1)

Here is the Google Sheet :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8IPkA__E9wm7oGORe-ckmIMxz47aK4u_dfA3Lc6OuU/edit#gid=0

**Table 1:**

| Budget No | Company | Department | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Amazon | HR |  |
| A | Amazon | DEV |  |
| A | Sum |  |  |
| B | Google | DEV |  |
| C | Microsoft | AI |  |
| D | Meta | Marketing |  |
| E | Oracle |  |  |

**Table 2**

| Budget No | Company | Department | 2023-10 | 2023-11 | 2023-12 | 2024-01 | 2024-02 | 2024-03 | 2024-04 | 2024-05 | 2024-06 | 2024-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Amazon | HR |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A | Amazon | DEV |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A | Sum |  | 20.000,00 € | 25.000,00 € | 30.000,00 € |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| B | Google | DEV | 800,00 € | 900,00 € | 1.000,00 € |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| C | Microsoft | AI | 500,00 € | 700,00 € | 900,00 € |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D | Meta | Marketing | 8.000,00 € | 5.000,00 € | 2.000,00 € |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| E | Oracle | DEV | 2.000,00 € | 3.000,00 € | 4.000,00 € |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Solution Table 1 in 2023-10**

| Budget No | Company | Department | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Amazon | HR |  |
| A | Amazon | DEV |  |
| A | Sum |  | 20.000,00 € |
| B | Google | DEV | 800,00 € |
| C | Microsoft | AI | 500,00 € |
| D | Meta | Marketing | 8.000,00 € |
| E | Oracle | DEV | 2.000,00 € |

**Solution Table 1 in 2023-11**

| Budget No | Company | Department | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Amazon | HR |  |
| A | Amazon | DEV |  |
| A | Sum |  | 25.000,00 € |
| B | Google | DEV | 900,00 € |
| C | Microsoft | AI | 700,00 € |
| D | Meta | Marketing | 5.000,00 € |
| E | Oracle | DEV | 3.000,00 € |

The data A6:C12 and A16-M22 are entered manually.

In table 1 (D6-D12), the corresponding budgets of the current month (B2) should always be entered by formula and it depends on which ""Budget No"", ""Company"" and ""Department"" it is.

There is a special feature here, namely the line ""Sum"", in which the departments of the same company share the budget and no department has its own budget.

Table 1 and Table 2 can look completely different, see Example 1 and Example 2. The logic stays the same.
I have already tried Vlookup, Index, Match but have never found a solution. Maybe I'm thinking too complicated and don't see the simple solution.

Comment: The question is a copy of [Get budgets that depend on 3 columns and one row in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/244010404) that already has an answer. See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(A5:C11;lambda(Σ;xlookup(join(;Σ);index(A15:A21&B15:B21&C15:C21);filter(D15:M21;eomonth(D14:M14;)=eomonth(now();));)))
```

- *also assumed here that `budget\company\dept` list may not be in the same order in both the tables*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also works great, but I took this because it is a bit easier to understand:
=let( 
  data; filter(D15:Z21; month(D14:Z14) = month(B1)); 
  map(A5:A11; B5:B11; C5:C11; lambda(budget; comp; dept; 
    filter(data; A15:A21 = budget; B15:B21 = comp; C15:C21 = dept) 
  )) 
)
Source: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/244010404/get-budgets-that-depend-on-3-columns-and-one-row-in-google-sheets